# Listing within tabular -- alignment

Tags: tables, listings

I have the following code where $q_1$ aligns in the middle. I would like to align it with the top line (`SELECT`). Is there a way to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=SQL}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$q_{1}:$ & \begin{lstlisting}
SELECT EMP.ENAME
FROM   EMP NATURAL JOIN ASG NATURAL JOIN PROJ
WHERE  PNAME="CAD/CAM"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `boxpos=t` option you can achieve the desired alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=SQL}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$q_{1}:$ & \begin{lstlisting}[boxpos=t]
SELECT EMP.ENAME
FROM   EMP NATURAL JOIN ASG NATURAL JOIN PROJ
WHERE  PNAME="CAD/CAM"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

From the [`listings` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

> `boxpos=〈b|c|t〉`: Sometimes the listingspackage puts a `\hbox` around a listing— or it couldn’t be  printed  or  even  processed  correctly.   The  key  determines  the  vertical alignment  to  the  surrounding  material:  bottom  baseline,  centered  or  topbaseline. [...]

The default alignment is, as you observed `c`.

Comment: Beautiful. Many thanks.